# How can I test affiliate program in my custom uber app using uber sdk?

Tags: ios, uber-api

I created a custom app, using uber sdk (https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk). I also have "connect" button along with singup option and I'm using affiliate program for US-based clients using "client_id" parameter during sign-in/up (https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/affiliate-program/introduction).

How can I test it, and how can I check if new users will be connected to my account?

Let's assume that I have app in production mode (running in real environment and approved by uber and apple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good question. Because signups / first trips are not in the self-serve analytics provided on the developer dashboard at developer.uber.com unfortunately I do not think there is really a way to test that a user signup / first trip has been attributed to your app.

As long as you are following these rules, the signups / first trips will be attributed to your app:

"Always link to https://m.uber.com/ul/?client_id=.
Always include your client_id in your deep link."

And payouts begin once an app reaches $250 in referral fees (so 50 signups/first trips attributed to an app). This FAQ might answer more q's about your affiliate questions: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/affiliate-program/faq

Comment: Is there any way to find out if we have 9 or 49 signups/first trips, before reaching the threshold of 50? Is there any notification that new signup has been attributed to my app?

Comment: No, there is not any self-serve analytics as mentioned. Not ideal, I know! As you might imagine Uber is trying to get users in many different channels (partners, ads, display, apps, etc etc) and the attribution waterfall is complicated. Getting these business metrics (as opposed to just straight API metrics) into the developer dashboard has been difficult.  This is a long way of saying that no self-serve signups/first trips are present & the first notification you would receive would be payment at $250. PS, can you please accept my answer? Thank you.

Comment: PS: just wanted to flag that the Uber API affiliate program is currently limited to US (in case you did not notice that in the affiliate FAQ) as I noticed your profile mentions Poland. Just a heads up!